# Inequalities and fractional norms

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, inequality

I have a question which is allegedly a dumb question, but I prefer to ask.

Let $s\in (0, 1)$ and let
$$
[u]_s = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^2}{|x - y|^{n+2s}}\, dx dy\right)^{1/2}
$$
be the Gagliardo seminorm of $u$, where $u : \mathbb{R}^n \to \mathbb{R}$ is a measurable function.

Moreover, let $a, b$ real numbers and consider the well known inequality
$$|(a+b)/2|^2 +|(a-b)/2|^2 \le 1/2 (|a|^2 +|b|^2) \quad\forall a, b\in\mathbb{R}.$$

The question is: one can employ the previous inequality to state that
$$[(u+v)/2]_s^2 +[(u-v)/2]_s^2 \le 1/2 ([u]_s^2 +[v]_s^2) \quad \text{ for any measurable function $u, v$ such that } [u]_s <\infty, \, [v]_s<\infty ?$$

I apologize again if that is a dumb question.

$\bf{EDIT:}$ Thanks to @rafexiap for his answer (+1). Anyways, the inequality involving $a, b$ remains true if I replace $2$ with $m$, for any $m>2$. In that case, you can not apply parallelogram law. Does the inequality
$$[(u+v)/2]_{s, m}^m +[(u-v)/2]_{s, m}^m \le 1/2 ([u]_{s, m}^m +[v]_{s, m}^m)$$
remain true?
Here
$$
[u]_{s, m} = \left(\int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}} \frac{|u(x) - u(y)|^m}{|x - y|^{n+sm}}\, dx dy\right)^{1/2}.
$$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us put
$$\langle u, v\rangle_s = \int_{\mathbb{R}^{2n}}\frac{[u(x)-u(y)][v(x)-v(y)]}{|x-y|^{n+2s}}dxdy.$$
This is the semi-inner product defining the Gagliardo seminorm.  Then the usual parallelogram law applies:
$$
[(u+v)/2]_s^2 + [(u-v)/2]_s^2 = \frac{1}{4}\langle u+v, u+v\rangle_s + \frac{1}{4}\langle u-v, u-v\rangle_s = \frac{1}{2}\langle u,u\rangle_s + \frac{1}{2}\langle v,v\rangle_s.
$$
So in fact you get the equality.

PS: note that you have a typo in the denominator of your definition of the seminorm, $2$ instead of $n$.